Convergence of sequences formed by orthocenters, incenters, and centroids in repeated triangle constructions
I asked this question on MSE here.

Given a scalene triangle $A_1B_1C_1$ , construct a triangle $A_{n+1}B_{n+1}C_{n+1}$ from the triangle $A_nB_nC_n$ where $A_{n+1}$ is the orthocenter of $A_nB_nC_n$, $B_{n+1}$ is the incenter of $A_nB_nC_n$ and $C_{n+1}$ is the centroid of $A_nB_nC_n$, My question is  If this process is repeated indefinitely would the sequences $\{A_n\}$, $\{B_n\}$, $\{C_n\} $ converge ?
There are only four possible scenarios:

The points will converge to a point.
The points will eventually stuck on a loop.
The points will completely diverge.
The points will eventually make an isosceles triangle (or equilateral triangle) which will end the sequence.

All of these scenarios would depend on the initial triangle. So given the initial triangle $A_1 B_1 C_1$  how to determine which of the four scenario would happen to the sequences $\{A_n\}$, $\{B_n\}$, $\{C_n\} $?
I tried to draw the first few triangles and see if the point will converge or not.






Graphing the first  25 triangles suggests that the sequence converge.

Here is the graphing the first 30 triangle, If anyone needs them.
If this is true that the three sequences will converge to a point this point will be unique to the triangle, I wonder what extra properties this point have.

Here is a python code that can calculate $A_n, B_n, C_n$
import math

print("Number of Triangles ")
n=int(input() )
m=max(n,50)

from decimal import Decimal
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = m
Decimal(10)**(-m)

# enter your coordinates here----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
B=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
C=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]

print("Enter the coordinates of A_1")
A[0]=Decimal(float (input() ))
A[1]=Decimal(float (input() ))
print("Enter the coordinates of B_1")
B[0]=Decimal(float (input() ))
B[1]=Decimal(float (input() ))
print("Enter the coordinates of C_1")
C[0]=Decimal(float (input() ))
C[1]=Decimal(float (input() ))

X=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
Y=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
Z=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]


#defining some useful functions----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def v(a,b):
    result= [b[0]-a[0], b[1]-a[1]]
    return result 
def dis(a,b):
    result =[Decimal(math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2+(a[1]-b[1])**2))]
    return result
def det1(a,b,c):
    result=[Decimal(a[0]*(b[1]-c[1])-a[1]*(b[0]-c[0])+b[0]*c[1]-b[1]*c[0])]
    return result
def det2(a,b,c):
    result=[Decimal(a[1]*((a[0]*c[0]+b[1]**2)-(b[0]*a[0]+c[1]**2))-(b[0]*c[0]+a[1]**2)*(b[1]-c[1])+b[1]*(b[0]*a[0]+c[1]**2)-(a[0]*c[0]+b[1]**2)*c[1])]
    return result
def det3(a,b,c):
    result=[Decimal((b[1]*c[1]+a[0]**2)*(b[0]-c[0])-a[0]*((a[1]*c[1]+b[0]**2)-(b[1]*a[1]+c[0]**2))+(a[1]*c[1]+b[0]**2)*c[0]-b[0]*(b[1]*a[1]+c[0]**2))]
    return result


for i in range (2,n+1):
    AB= dis(A,B)[0]
    BC= dis(B,C)[0]
    CA= dis(C,A)[0]

    #Here to calculate A_n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    X[0]=(det2(A,B,C)[0])/(det1(A,B,C)[0])
    X[1]=(det3(A,B,C)[0])/(det1(A,B,C)[0])

    #Here to calculate B_n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Y[0]=(BC*A[0]+CA*B[0]+AB*C[0])/(AB+BC+CA)
    Y[1]=(BC*A[1]+CA*B[1]+AB*C[1])/(AB+BC+CA)

    #Here to calculate C_n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Z[0]=(A[0]+B[0]+C[0])/(3)
    Z[1]=(A[1]+B[1]+C[1])/(3)

    A[0]=X[0]
    A[1]=X[1]
    B[0]=Y[0]
    B[1]=Y[1]
    C[0]=Z[0]
    C[1]=Z[1]

    print(f"A_{i}= {A}")
    print(f"B_{i}= {B}")
    print(f"C_{i}= {C}")
    print("\n")


It seems that the limit point (assuming it exists) in not in the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers,

$A_{200}$= (8.6517261735796624259738866329868556565084282680250211296497747096925130468748471270311512731368352997396376217183698044561298843731579912635996830539690878380408962952883253860600049288093494865497599 , 2.6448983193088667221426565924157297722624220231935390980264815214196851480235776604874831322040452866206749638086977011401669267140152803272215053706747629093984074903821689253277924827830127005097490)

the distance between  $A_{200} $ and $\overline {B_1C_1}$ (in the triangle 6-9-13) is
0.53607927192029201038720734406762285666375854671162570169736131240500819198707277389944959286896591541232676930403964641142971002571581881565561923735731504211210609184202055267373207796429563740347276
which doesn't exist on this list.

If we denote the sides lengths of $A_1B_1C_1$ by $a_1,b_1 ,c _1$ and those of $A_2B_2C_2$ by $a _2,b_2 ,c _2$, then this defines in a natural way a mapping $\Phi$ on three space and your question is asking for the dynamics of its iterates.  It is possible to compute $\Phi$ explicitly (I have done so) but the expression is rather complicated and I have no idea about its dynamics.  However, one can use it for some simulations.  The few attempts that I have made look as if they are going to a point but they are hardly enough to use even as the basis  for a conjecture.

Well, if my simulations are anything to go by, the iterates of $\Phi$ tend to $(0,0,0)$ for triangles of very different shapes (i.e., the triangles converge to a point), in rather interesting ways,  and so I will stick my neck out and conjecture that this is the case for any shape.

@crow If the triangles converge to a point this point is unique to the triangle, I wonder what extra properties this point have. The only point (which is very unique to a triangle) that I didn't include is the circumcenter  but this sequence doesn't converge to it.

If the sequence of points converges to a point, it is possible that (considering angles alone) it converges to a specific triangle. (Or not.)

@Daniel Asimov It appears to ocillate between approximations to two specific triangles.  Again this is based on a few crude simulations so pure speculation.  But the dynamics of the iteration proposed by the OP seem to be quite fascinating.

How is the map defined for degenerate triangles, e.g. if A, B, C are collinear? (or maybe this never happens starting from a non-degenerate triangle?)

@PietroMajer It is not defined, in fact if the sequence reached a degenerate triangles starting from    a non-degenerate one the sequence will stop as I sated in the point 4

@crow  i’d  say  a bit less ${40000 \choose 3}+40000^2$; still enough,  for a while  (then we may iterate)

This is reminiscent of a kind of “iterated mean” process (see this question on this subject), but in dimension 2 and invariant under Euclidean similitudes rather than in dimension 1. To prove convergence you probably need to rephrase it as a map in the modulus space of triangles, but it is unlikely that the point will have interesting properties, as already the arithmetic-quadratic mean of two real numbers is largely unstudied (as per previously linked question).

@crow It seems that the limit point is not any of the centers listed in ETC.

Is it possible to prove that the area is strictly decreasing?

@DarrenLi The area is not  strictly decreasing

19th version of this question.

It looks like for a triangle whose side lengths are some values close to $1,0.05730946,0.959413912$, the $9^{\text{th}}$ iteration is an isometric copy of the original triangle but around $5$ times bigger. This means that this triangle would satisfy your scenario $3$: "The points will completely diverge". That said,


I am worried about the precision of my geogebra, especially since the 4$^{\text{th}}$ iteration of the triangle I mention is almost degenerate.


I'm not even going to try to prove it rigorously



Also, it seems like in most cases (likely except in some measure $0$ subset of the set of triangles, if you give some reasonable measure to the set of triangles), the ratio between the sides of the triangles will converge to something close to $(1:0.31720:0.85873)$. And then your Scenario 1 will be satisfied, and the triangles will converge to a point. But convergence to the ratios I mentioned above is very slow

@SaúlRM What is the thing special about $1,0.05730946,0.959413912$ that make the sequence diverge (How did you discover it?)? and what are these numbers ? Graphing this triangle seems to diverge but I have my doubts

I will leave an answer shortly explaining a bit more

BTW I don't know if this is useful or not but the triangle with sides $1, \ 0.7239, \ 0.365808$ the point of convergence is very close to the obtuse angle

Below I give an example of a triangle which seems to grow exponentially when iterating the process from the question (so it satisfies Scenario 3). The example relies on the existence of a fixed point of a function $F^9:\mathcal{T}\to\mathcal{T}$ defined below. Computational evidence suggests that the fixed point exists, but I have not proved it.
Note that to each triangle $T$ you can assign two unique numbers $x,y\in[0,1]$ such that $1\geq y\geq x$ and the sides of the triangle $T$ are in proportion $(1:x:y)$. Let's call the point $(x,y)$ the "shape" of $T$, $S(T)$.
Then the space of shapes of (non-isosceles) triangles is the set $\mathcal{T}:=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2;y>x,x+y>1\}$, the interior of an triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of area $\frac{1}{4}$.
Now, for each triangle $T$ denote by $f(T)$ the triangle formed by the orthocenter, incenter and centroid of $T$. And define a map $F:\mathcal{T}\to\mathcal{T}$ by $F(S(T))=S(f(T))$ (actually, $F$ is not defined in the entire $\mathcal{T}$).
After observing the behaviour of the map $F^n:\mathcal{T}\to\mathcal{T}$ for big $n$, it seems that for almost all $S\in\mathcal{T}$, the sequence $S,F(S),F^2(S),\dots$ will converge to a point which I will call $P_0$, approximately $(0.31720,0.85873)$. However, convergence is very slow. In the big figure below, I start with a point $A\in\mathcal{T}$ and denote $A_n=F^{n-1}(A)$ for $n=2,3,4,5,11,21,31,41,51,81,141$. $A_{141}$ is already close to $P_0$. In the small figure, I chose an initial point $A$ much closer to $P_0$.


I have not tried to prove that $P_0$ is a stable fixed point of the dynamical system $F:\mathcal{T}\to\mathcal{T}$.
Now, the interesting thing would be finding triangles which satisfy Scenario $3$ (or $2$, but such a triangle seems unlikely to exist) from the question: the iterates of the triangle $T$ diverge. There is a simple way to do that: we just need to find a point $S=S(T)\in\mathcal{T}$ such that $S=F^n(S)$, for some $n$, and such that $f^n(T)$ is bigger in size than $T$. Then the triangles $T,f(T),f^2(T),\dots$ will get exponentially bigger with time.
Thus, the question becomes about finding fixed points of powers of the map $F:\mathcal{T}\to\mathcal{T}$. For most fixed points $S=F^n(S)$, we have that $f^n(T)$ is smaller than $T$, so they are no use. But it seems there is a point $P$ near $(0.05730946, 0.959413912)$ such that $P=F^9(P)$ and such that, if $T$ is a triangle with $S(T)=P$, then $f^9(T)$ is around $5$ times bigger than $T$.
One could possibly prove the existence of the fixed point $P$ by studying the derivative of $F^9$ near $P$, but that is easier said than done. Below I leave a picture of the triangle $T$ (small, black, two of its vertices are $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$) and its ninth iterate (brown).


How did you compute $A_{141}$?

I made a geogebra tool to compute the function $F(p)$ for any point $p$, then another geogebra tool that computes $F^{10}(p)$ and applied it $14$ times. Surely inefficient, but surprisingly geogebra can handle it well. If you want I can send you the files (my email is in my profile)

Have you tried to find $F(p)$ explicitly as a function of $p$? It may be feasible to show that $F()$ is one to one and either strictly expanding or strictly contracting in some neighborhood of your fixed point, and that would ensure its existence.

I considered trying that, but look at the small image, where $d(A,P_0)<10^{-4}$. I am pretty sure $F$ will not be contractible near $P_0$. In any case there is no harm checking whether the eigenvalues of the derivative are $<1$ in norm near $P_0$, I will try using software to do that. But if so they have to be really close to $1$

I just tried and it seems the function $F$ is too complicated for my matlab to process (it gave me an error, maybe I made some mistake in the process). If someone can compute it they are welcome to try though, I am curious about whether $DF$ has eigenvalues of norm $<1$ near $P_0$ or they have norm $1$

I made a similar question on MSE here, I think you might be interested.
